# Centering nav bar in header with logo

Tags: html, css, header, nav

Looking for a little help with a project, I am trying to get a nav bar centered inside a header with a logo on the left.

HTML

```
<header>
  <img src="http://s32.postimg.org/5bebu6mbl/Image_5_8_16_at_12_10_PM.jpgHome" />
  <div id="nav">
    <span><a href="#">Home</a></span>
    <span><a href="#"><button>Televeisions</button></a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Electronics</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Services</a></span>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header {
  height: 5.5em;
  background: gray;
  color: Black;
  text-align: justify;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#nav span a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjL3j8nr/1/)

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to your question?

Comment: Sorry , Having some trouble 
https://jsfiddle.net/xjL3j8nr/

Comment: If one of the answers completed your question, please mark it by clicking the green check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nav width 100% is forcing the nav below the image. I added overflow: hidden to the header, floated the img left, and put a margin-top on the #nav.

Adjust your CSS to something like this:

```
header {
  height: 5.5em;
  background: gray;
  color: Black;
  text-align: justify;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
#nav {
  width: 600px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2.5em;
}

#nav span a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

You can adjust the margin, etc. to style how you want from there on out.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/Tambe257/pen/XdGdLZ

Answer (score 0):

Use positioning on your parent element and your child elements that will be nested inside. Here's a quick example

```
header {
  height: 5.5em;
  background: gray;
  color: Black;
  text-align: justify;
  position:relative;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 top:2em;
 position:absolute;
}

#nav span a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;

}
```